# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri not working in asp.net core 2.0 (Using System.Web)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Please I am trying to get my domain url using the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri in asp.net core 2.0 but "Request" is not in the System.Web namespace. and this is the popular way of achieving this. Please is it different in ASP.NET core 2.0. Please help.
Below is the line of code

```
var verifyUrl = "/user/VerifyAccount/" + activationCode;
var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, verifyUrl);
```

Normally "link" should give me "http://myDomainName/user/VerifyAccount/276ye6tfhsgt63t6e" 
but the System.Web.Request is not working

Comment: System.Web is webforms it is not part of asp.net core

Comment: @JoeAudette Please How can I achieve this then?

Answer (score 4):

The `HttpRequest` object is different in ASP.NET Core. It no longer contains `Url` property. You'll need to build your URI manually:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
{
    Scheme = Request.Scheme,
    Host = Request.Host.ToString(),
    Path = $"/user/VerifyAccount/{activationCode}"
};

var link = uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

The `Request` variable will be available by default in your controller and such. If you find that there is no `Request` variable, you can try `HttpContext.Request`. If you're doing this inside a view, you'll need `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Pratt I am using this using this in a function in my user repository and will be using IUserRepository to call it in the controller. But in my UserRepository.cs it not working even with HttpContext. what should i do please

Comment: Are you injecting IHttpContextAccessor?

Comment: Patt. No, I'm not.

Comment: You need to. Register it with `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`, and then iniect it into your repo class. Then, you can access `HttpContext` off of that. You must also be within the request pipeline, or it will simply be null.

Comment: I suggest using `Host = Request.Host.Host` instead of `ToString()`, as this strips the port (if present), which is invalid in the `Host` property. You could then add the line `Port = Request.Host.Port ?? -1` (-1 is the default port if not set).